# Foursquare Explore API not providing venue tips on certain accounts

Tags: json, api, foursquare

When using the Foursquare Developer API to perform a venue search, I receive different results depending on the account being used.

For a given authorised query (for example, https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=40.7,-74) I am given back a collection of items with "reasons" and "venue" objects. On some accounts, it also provides "tips" data; on others it does not.

Is this additional information dependent on certain account settings, or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The explore endpoint is tailored to each user and provides dynamic recommendations depending on social context, time of day, and user interests. Thus, two queries are likely to contain different content depending on who is querying the API.

For example, if a friend has left a tip at a nearby venue, it's more likely that you'll see that in your explore results, because it provides social reinforcement to the recommendation.

For other venues, there might be signals more important than tips, so a tip is not surfaced.

The official foursquare apps provide good examples of this data in action, as the explore result panes change format slightly from recommendation to recommendation.

Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Unfortunately this is highly unlikely to be the cause of the issue; for some accounts at least one tip will appear on nigh-on every single venue anywhere, but others will have no tips data at all.

I appreciate that results will be filtered differently and provide different data depending on the user, but this can't be intended behaviour, surely.

Comment: course it can. If you want to just search for venues nearby use the venues/search endpoint

Comment: But venues/search lacks a lot of information you only get through venues/explore, including the user tips I'm trying to include!

Comment: you can get tips from a separate api call pretty easily though no?

Comment: Certainly, but aside from rate limit concerns I feel there is still a problem to solve: For some users the tips data is reliably present in the explore request, and for others they consistently never get any tips.